# Texture from 3d coat imported to blender has pixelated depth

Tags: texturing, import, texture-painting, texture-baking, baking

I Painted something in 3d coat with depth and when I import it into blender by adding the cube as an obj then going into the principled BSDF in shader editer and clicking ctrl + shift + t to add all the normals and texture stuff it comes out with the depth pixelated like this:
[image]

In 3dcoat It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using bump texture for normal mapping, so that you have these artifacts. Instead, get Normal map texture (looks purple) and use it instead of bump. Then using *ctrl + shift + t* from Node Wrangler addon, do not select bump map, select normal map instead.

You can also use [blender app link for 3d coat](https://3dcoat.com/app-links/) for easy transition between apps

Answer (score 0):

Something labelled "normal" should not typically go through a bump map node.  It should go through a normal map node instead.  It's possible that what you've labelled "normal" is, in fact, a depth map-- it's also possible that it's a normal map.  The two are not the same.  We can't know without seeing the image.

If you're sure that it is a bump map, a bump distance of 1.0 is very unusual, even though it's the default.  More likely values are 0.005, 0.001, etc.  Bump maps are not typically mapped into the 0-1 *meter* range because it reduces their precision.  You should probably not be using a depth of 1.0 unless your plan is to render, let's say, an entire county, at Blender's recommended scale of 1u=1m.

Additionally, based just on the complaint, I would recommend checking the file format.  JPEGs are totally unsuitable for use as bump maps.  They have built-in lossy compression that works great for reducing the memory footprint of photos (what JPEGs are designed for) but which quantizes grayscale values, leading to pixellation when used as depth maps.

Actually telling you why, without just playing a guessing game, would require a lot more info, and the best way to provide that info is with a file (with packed textures, in this case.)  I understand that, here, the question is half a year old as of time of answering, and that you are probably done with the project, problem solved or no.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your model has tris only, since 3d coat uses a triangulation algorithm different from blender and visualizes it all internally as tris